# Merge columns and Sub Select list

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query simply looks like:

```
SELECT col1, col2,
    (SELECT col3, col4 FROM Table2)
FROM Table1
```

Wanted result is:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
-------------------------
ABC  | DEF  | GHI  | JKL
...  | ...  | ...  | ...
```

But I am getting an error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

How to merge lists and current rows?

Comment: Do u have any common fields between 2 tables, I guess u need `Union all` not Merge

Comment: You are likely going to get a "subquery returns multiple rows error" when you figure out to remove one of the columns.  Sample data, desired results, and explanations really help convey what you want to do.  As a general rule, non-working queries are not likely to convey that information.

Comment: Your sample is a little vague.. that said, are you looking for CROSS JOIN ?

Comment: Add some sample table data and its expected result. Formatted text, please (no images.)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT col1, 
       col2,
       (SELECT col3 FROM Table2 as t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id) as col3,
       (SELECT col4 FROM Table2 as t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id) as col4
FROM Table1 as t1
```

or even better:

```
SELECT t1.col1, 
       t1.col2,
       t2.col3,
       t2.col4
FROM Table1 as t1
JOIN Table2 as t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
```

if you don't have a field to join both tables then:

```
SELECT t1.col1, 
       t1.col2,
       t2.col3,
       t2.col4
FROM Table1 as t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 as t2
```